# Why is my pointer assignment causing a seemingly unrelated value to change?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to solve an interval problem using double pointers. The basic premise is to store double pointers to an Interval struct in my map so I can update the interval without needing to iterate over any other values in my map. Using double pointers seems to be causing some unexpected changes to my intervals, and I don't understand why.

Here's my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int, char>> sequence = { 
        {0,'a'},
        {1,'-'},
        {2,'b'},
        {3,'c'},
        {4,'-'},
        {5,'d'},
        {6,'e'},
        {7,'-'},
        {8,'f'},
        {10,'g'},
        {11,'-'},
        {12, '-'}
    };

    struct Interval {
        string word;
        bool startH;
        bool endH;
        Interval(string word) : word(word), startH(false), endH(false) {}

    };

    Interval* hyphen = new Interval("-");
    Interval** hPtr = &hyphen;

    auto consolidate = [&hPtr](Interval**& left, Interval**& right) {
        //cout << "\t(" << (*left)->word << " " << (*right)->word << ")" << endl;
        if (left == hPtr && right == hPtr) return;

        if (left == hPtr) {
            (*right)->startH = true;
        }
        else if (right == hPtr) {
            (*left)->endH = true;
        }
        else {
            (*right)->startH = (*left)->startH;
            (*right)->word = (*left)->word + (*right)->word;
            (*left) = (*right);
        }

        if ((*right)->startH && (*right)->endH) {
            cout << "RESULT: " << (*right)->word << endl;
        }
        else if ((*left)->startH && (*left)->endH) {
            cout << "RESULT: " << (*left)->word << endl;
        }
    };


    unordered_map<int, Interval**> intervals;

    for (auto pair : sequence) {
        int index = pair.first;
        char c = pair.second;
        cout << "----" << index << ", " << c << "-----" << endl;
        
        int preIndex = index - 1;
        int postIndex = index + 1;
        auto it_pre = intervals.find(preIndex);
        auto it_post = intervals.find(postIndex);
        
        //HERE 1
        //if (it_pre != intervals.end()) cout << (*(it_pre->second))->word << endl;
        
        Interval** currentIntervalPtr;

        if (c == '-') {
            currentIntervalPtr = hPtr;
        }
        else {
            Interval* currentInterval = new Interval(string(1, c));
            currentIntervalPtr = &currentInterval;
        }

        //HERE 2
        //if (it_pre != intervals.end()) cout << (*(it_pre->second))->word << endl;

        if (it_pre != intervals.end()) {
            Interval** prePtr = it_pre->second;
            //cout << "PRE: <" << (*currentIntervalPtr)->word << ", " << (*prePtr)->word << ">>" << endl;
            consolidate(prePtr, currentIntervalPtr);
        }

        if (it_post != intervals.end()) {
            Interval** postPtr = it_post->second;
            //cout << "POST: <" << (*currentIntervalPtr)->word << ", " << (*postPtr)->word << ">>" << endl;
            consolidate(currentIntervalPtr, postPtr);
        }
        
        intervals[index] = currentIntervalPtr;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Between my two print statements (HERE 1 and HERE 2), the value of (*(it_pre->second))->word changes. All I've done between these statements is create a new, unrelated Interval, so I don't understand why my map values are changing.

Any insights would be appreciated. I'm new to using double pointers, so I might just be overlooking something simple.

Comment: `Interval* hyphen = new Interval("-");` -- `Interval** hPtr = &hyphen;` -- `[&hPtr](Interval**& left, Interval**& right)` -- With the useless use of pointers like this, it isn't a surprise the code is not behaving correctly.  Why are you using `new` to declare a `hyphen`?  There is just too much pointerism's in the code you have now, when it wouldn't be surprising if using no pointers would work, and without all of the pointer gymnastics.

Comment: `currentIntervalPtr = &currentInterval;` stores the address of a local variable that immediately goes out of scope. I would have expected your compiler to say something about that.

Comment: How can I assign the value of the pointer to a new struct and keep it in scope? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: "using double pointer" - wow, haven't needed those in 20+ years..

Comment: @JesperJuhl Probably haven't had to write a singly linked list, either. Ain't the Standard Library wonderful?

Comment: @user4581301 "Probably haven't had to write a singly linked list, either" - What on earth are you talking about? As a matter of fact, I *have* implemented linked lists - how is that relevant?

Comment: @JesperJuhl When hand-rolling a singly linked list I usually have a couple pointer-to-pointers in there.

Comment: @user4581301 You don't need double pointers to implement a linked list.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Of course you don't. I just find it much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

> ```
>         else {
>             Interval* currentInterval = new Interval(string(1, c));
>             currentIntervalPtr = &currentInterval;
>         }
> ```

... you are assigning to `currentIntervalPtr` the address of a variable local to that block.  The lifetime of that pointed-to pointer variable ends when execution of the block terminates, after which dereferencing `currentIntervalPtr` produces undefined behavior.

Note well that it doesn't matter that the `Interval` itself lives on.  Its lifetime is entirely separate from and independent of the lifetime of any pointer pointing to it.

I'm not quite tracking what you're trying to gain with the double pointers here, but perhaps instead of a pointer to a block-scope variable, you can store the `Interval` pointers in a vector declared outside the loop, and use pointers to the elements of that vector.  But I'm also thinking that instead of a `vector<Interval *>` and double pointers, you could probably make it easier on yourself with a `vector<Interval>` and single pointers -- that assuming you don't want to engage in a deeper refactoring.

Comment: Using a vector is a much cleaner way of what I'm trying to do, so thanks! I was overly complicating it.

Answer (score 1):

Both [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76948833) and [Jun H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21933340/jun-h)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76948827) identify the specific cause of the bug in your program correctly. But - I would say the origin of your problem is your use of pointers.

**You should not use pointers unless you actually need them.**

It's not just me saying this; see:

- C++ Core Guideline R.5:  [Prefer scoped objects, don’t heap-allocate unnecessarily](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r5-prefer-scoped-objects-dont-heap-allocate-unnecessarily).
- [this useful explanation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/163279/63497) on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange.
- [this polemic presentation](https://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1) of typical cases where people use pointers, but don't need to.

You really don't need pointers here:

- When you want a new interval, just create one the simple and regular way: `Interval(my_string)`; and pass it or assign it wherever you need to. Doing this will also work well with returning Intervals from functions rather than passing in pointers to intended result locations.
- When you want to refer to an existing interval (which you should also avoid doing overmuch), use a C++ *reference* to wherever it is you found it.

This would also help make your code simpler and more legible. Right now, with you repeatedly changing already-inserted intervals, it's not clear what the intervals map even holds.

---

Minor nitpicks:

- If `intervals` is indexed by int value, and you iterate int values sequentially, why not just use an `std::vector<Interval>`?
- You should avoid `using namespace std`, and just do `using` on what you actually use. See:
   [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1593077)